# Sendmail and SwiftMailerBundle on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

Hello I am using Symfony2 and the SwiftMailerBundle, when i was using gmail like my transport, was so easy, but now i need use sendmail.

Here is the part of my parameters.yml

```
mailer_transport: sendmail
mailer_host: /usr/sbin/sendmail
mailer_user: no-replay@mysite.com
mailer_password: null
```

And here is the config.yml:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/exim -bs');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

as per the documentation :

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#using-the-sendmail-transport

you need to create a Swift_SendmailTransport first then instantiate your mailer with it.

This question may help : [Configure Symfony2/Swiftmailer to use "sendmail -t"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958957/configure-symfony2-swiftmailer-to-use-sendmail-t)