# Symfony 2: how to send an email using Swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to send emails using Swiftmailer with Symfony 2.

This is the simple function in the controller

```
public function sendEmailAction() {

 $name = 'Test';

 $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
 $message = $mailer->createMessage()
    ->setSubject('Ciao')
    ->setFrom('send@example.com')
    ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
    ->setBody($this->renderView('dashboard/email.html.twig',array('name' => $name)), 'text/html');



    $mailer->send($message);

   return $this->redirectToRoute('dashboard');
```

In the parameters.yml I have following configuration

```
parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: symfony
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: e23a8d7b075fa3c7e56b10186a24cf2790a3169a
```

And this is the **config.yml** one

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

Unfortunately I cannot send emails...

Comment: I would first try to send an email from command line using that settings. Are you sure that SMTP is locally working ?

Comment: Are you sure your email doesn't get considered as a spam or isn't filtered by the firewall because he is not trusted-email-compliant ?

Comment: The SMTP is locally not working...

Comment: Are there any errors in the Symfony log?

Comment: Pls refer the tutorial it's showing how to configure and send email with Swiftmailer. http://sgeek.org/send-email-attachment-using-swiftmailer-symfony/

Answer (score 4):

Please read the documentation about ["How to send an Email"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/index.html)

> Swift Mailer provides a number of methods for sending emails,
>   including using an SMTP server, using a local install of sendmail, or
>   even using a GMail account.

**Example with mail transport**

```
mailer_transport: mail
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
```

**Example with smtp**

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: your@gmail.com
mailer_password: *******
```

**Example with sendmail** : read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958957/configure-symfony2-swiftmailer-to-use-sendmail-t)

```
mailer_transport: sendmail
mailer_host: /usr/bin/sendmail # wherever your mail is
#mailer_user: ~
#mailer_password: ~
```

**Example with GMail account**

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: your@gmail.com
mailer_password: *******
```

And use it like this

```
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('from@example.com')
        ->setTo('to@example.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'HelloBundle:Hello:email.txt.twig',
                array('name' => $name)
            )
        )
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, exactly what was needed.  Thanks!

Comment: How do I check if the e-mail was sent? I'm using smtp with a completely bogus host, user and pass, and still ->send() returns 1, and not exception raised. How does that make any sense?