# How to send an email with swiftmailer - Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, email

I make a small website for a school project with symfony 3 and still learning.

I have a contact form where i try to get informations and send them to an administrator email adress.
I tried with 2 personal adress to test but it didn't work, i never receive the email.
I try to switch between different mailer_transport too, using a gmail adress for the gmail transport.
I don't understand very well how work a smtp server (working on it).

Here is my parameters.yml :

```
parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: symfony
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: sendmail
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: my.adress@email.com
mailer_password: myPassword
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

And here is the code in my controller, where i use some elements get from the contact form.

```
$mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('[WebSite] - '.$name.' - '.$date)
    ->setFrom('mySecond.adress@email.com')
    ->setTo('my.adress@email.com')
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'CoachSportifBundle::email.html.twig',
            array('name' => $name,
                'email' => $email,
                'message' => $message,
                'date' => $date
            )
        ),
        'text/html'
    );
$this->get('mailer')->send($mail);
```

the project is in php 5.6 and Symfony 3.2 and i work with wampserver 3.0.6.

I need some help so i can receive an email send from my form,
and if someone can explain me the difference between differents mailer_transport it would be wonderfull.

Thanks a lot and have a good day

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this post:
[Configure Symfony2/Swiftmailer to use "sendmail -t"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958957/configure-symfony2-swiftmailer-to-use-sendmail-t)

Based on the last post, try these configuration changes:

```
mailer_transport: sendmail
mailer_host: 'C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t' # wherever your mail is
#mailer_user: ~
#mailer_password: ~
```

See if that works.

Here is a article on Wikipedia to read on message transfer agents:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent

Comment: You can also try using forward slash in case the above doesn't work, like so: `'C:/wamp/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t'` The path could be different...