# How to configure MAILER_URL in .env file of Symfony 4 to send e-mails via sendmail with Swift_Mailer?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, swiftmailer, symfony4

I am working on a Symfony 4 app using `Swift_Mailer` to send e-mails with.
Since there is no possibility in my case to use SMTP (don't ask why…) I have to use something like `sendmail`.

By default the config of Swift Mailer is done in Symfony's `.env` file in URL notation in an option named `MAILER_URL`. The default value is "`null://localhost`" which doesn't send mails at all.

All I could find for what the value has to be is an example for Gmail or for SMTP in general as documented in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html) as well as in the sample .env as generated by Composer.

Default content of .env:

```
# …

###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
# For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
# Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
MAILER_URL=null://localhost
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###

# …
```

What I don't know and therefore what my question is:

**What do I need to do to make `sendmail` work with this?**

I already tried something like:

```
MAILER_URL=sendmail://localhost
```

and

```
MAILER_URL=sendmail://my-domain.com
```

but without success so far.

When using the console command

```
bin/console swiftmailer:email:send
```

I even get an "[OK] 1 emails were successfully sent." as result, but in fact no e-mail is sent.
(… No spooling, by the way. `bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send` returns "0 emails sent".)
Mail delivery seems to be interupted or so, since the mails won't arraive at my mail account, also my SPAM is empty.

Directly invoking the `sendmail` command on the other hand does work. (My test mails arrive at my SPAM though, but still: The mails are sent.)

**Again, how do I have to configure the `MAILER_URL` for `Swift_Mailer` in my `.env` in Symfony 4 to use `sendmail`?**

Is it possible at all?

Comment: i've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958957/configure-symfony2-swiftmailer-to-use-sendmail-t) on symfony 2.Try to adapt to .env variables !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, the notation already was correct. So this one is valid for using `sendmail`:

```
MAILER_URL=sendmail://my-domain.com
```

My actual problem was that spooling of mails was active. I commented out the `spool` entry from my `swiftmailer.yaml` config.

Having a look into the Symfony Profiler helped me a lot here, by the way.

… My mails are still not arriving, but I am sure this has nothing to do with the `MAILER_URL`. So, my question is answered.

Comment: As soon as I edit "switftmailer.yaml" all pages with contact forms go blanc. Could somebody elaborate how to do?

Comment: @kghbln Maybe you should ask  new question for that. To me it sounds like it could be … well … anything. Invalid YAML syntax, for instance. Or any other kind of misconfiguration. Blank pages however are pretty often just 500 Internal server errors. Those are usally logged. → Watch your error logs, please. I hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah I should ask a new question. I spend many hours trying to integrate Symfony with Postfix. The servers log is irritatingly empty and I just removed the line from the yaml file which was the last line in there anyways. I am a bit in despair since I believe this is a task of probably an hour max and so far I spent many hours :( Enough lamentation for now. :)

Answer (score 1):

commenting spool in yaml fixed issue for me

Comment: As soon as I edit "switftmailer.yaml" all pages with contact forms go blanc. Could somebody elaborate how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this config:

```
swiftmailer:
url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
spool: { type: 'memory' }
transport: 'sendmail'
command: '/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t'
```

Path to file:

> /my_sf4_project/config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml

I'm using Symfony 4.3.1 and SwiftMailer 6.2.0. You can read in SwiftMailer bundle documentation that:

```
/**
 * Start the standalone SMTP session if running in -bs mode.
 */
```

and then:

```
/**
 * Set the command to invoke.
 *
 * If using -t mode you are strongly advised to include -oi or -i in the flags.
 * For example: /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
 * Swift will append a -f<sender> flag if one is not present.
 *
 * The recommended mode is "-bs" since it is interactive and failure notifications
 * are hence possible.
 *
 * @param string $command
 *
 * @return $this
 */
```

Path to file with these adnotations:

> vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/SendmailTransport.php

Before changing into '/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t' i was receiving error from SwiftMailer:

> app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 220 but got an empty response [] []

After changing sendmail parameters now i'm sending mails successfully.

Comment: Of course my .env config is:

MAILER_URL=sendmail://my-domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got your problem correctly but in my case I use a Gmail account and here is the 23rd line of my .env file

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://myadress@gmail.com:myemailpassword@localhost
```

Have you already installed the SwiftMailer by `composer require symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` ?
(Sorry for my english)